# Jenkinks xml is is not a valid file

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to setup jobs for each of our suites in Jenkins, all jobs work locally - however when trying to run from Jenkins they are failing out. My understanding is that it has something to do with the configuration for surefire and or Jenkins but I'm not sure what I'm missing:

```
11:08:40 [ERROR] 
11:08:40 [ERROR] Please refer to /var/jenkins_home/workspace/AutomatedEmailTests/framework/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
11:08:40 [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
11:08:40 [ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
11:08:40 [ERROR] Suite file /framework/TestSuites/AutomatedEmailTests.xml is not a valid file
11:08:40 [ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
11:08:40 [ERROR] Suite file /framework/TestSuites/AutomatedEmailTests.xml is not a valid file
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:657)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:283)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:246)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1161)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1002)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:848)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
11:08:40 [ERROR]    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

Pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId></groupId>
    <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
         <testng.files.location>src/TestSuites/</testng.files.location>
    <testng.file>testng.xml</testng.file>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <gridUrl></gridUrl>
    </properties>
    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>${SuiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.webdriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdriver-chrome</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.7376</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.stephenc.monte</groupId>
            <artifactId>monte-screen-recorder</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I tried adding adding the following into goals to troubleshoot but had no luck `test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=/framework/TestSuites/AutomatedEmailTests.xml`

Jenkins:
[image]

Comment: It says that "AutomatedEmailTests.xml is not a valid file", check this file on Jenkins server.

Comment: Jenkins server pulling latest merge each run, file should be fine

Answer (score 0):

`/framework/` got duplicated somewhere in the troubleshooting process, removing it fixed it.